# Добавление программы в автозапуск

Tags: golang

Как сделать добавление программы в автозапуск Windows?

Был следущий код который написан ниже, он добавлял но при запуске Windows программа не запускалась.

```go
dir, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
path := path.Join(dir, "EveryNasa.exe")

k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.CURRENT_USER,
    `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`,
    registry.QUERY_VALUE|registry.SET_VALUE)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer k.Close()

err = k.SetStringValue("EveryNasa", strings.Replace(path, "/", "\\", -1))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Разницы особой быть не должно, если путь в реестре точный, Вы пробовали в этот путь добавлять другую программу например калькулятор?

Comment: Если честно то нет, сейчас попытаюсь, мне для запуска программы нужны админ права, и при запуске она их запрашивает, возможно что это из-за этого?

Comment: Сделал другую программу с выводом уведомлений и запускается, не пойму почему с этим проектом не работает

Comment: да вероятно дело в правах

Comment: при добавлении вручную можно выбрать опцию запуска с наивысшими правами, остается только найти где она прописывается в реестре

Comment: Сейчас сделал без запроса прав и при запуске будет еще консоль открыватся, но сейчас перезапустился и консоль не открылась, никаких признаков о том что программа запустилась

Comment: Мне бы сделать по возможности что бы программа сама добавляля и это работало

Comment: из того что я понял по этой теме админ права задаются в свойствах екзешника - выставляется галочка  запускать с правами админа, т.е. через скрипт это не сделать скорее всего

Comment: Ну по сути да, я это делаю через модуль go-winres, в коде я пытался но там свой прикол какой то

Comment: и я думаю не плохо записывать логи по ходу выполнения, чтобы не совсем вслепую

Comment: Даа... Если бы программа запускалась бы автоматически, у меня еще сделан трэй но его нет как и консоли

Comment: Нужно глянуть журнал системных ошибок, там должно тоже что-то прописаться

Comment: ~1/2 Кода на Golang я перевел на логи но файл даже не создался

Comment: а что в системном журнале ошибок?

Comment: Если я все правильно нажал то ничего.

P.s зашел в Журнал Событый -> `Microsoft-Windows-SENSE/Operational`

Comment: желательно найти логи уровня приложения, у меня например так в 10ке Windows Logs -> Application по идее там и будут все краши приложений

Comment: Ничего связанного с автозапуском не нашел

Comment: Здесь только 2 варианта либо приложение падает, либо даже не запускается, совсем не запускаться она не может при условии что галочка на запуск с админ правами установлен, и другая программа запускалась, значит - падает, если падает то должны оставаться системные логи. В принципе вариантов исследования больше нет. А сама программа без автозапуска вообще запускается? Конечно пути к файлу тоже могут влиять... но угадывать можно долго)

Comment: Программа без автозапуска запускается и все ок. "галочка на запуск с админ правами установлен"? Она не работет с ними и без них. .exe-ник находится в папке со всеми файлам проекта, повторюсь если программу самому запустить то все ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я смог сделать так, чтобы программа запускалась при входе в систему. Раньше я это делал через реестр, а сейчас создавал LNK-ярлык в папке:

```
C:\Users\your_usr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Как создавать LNK-ярлык, я нашел на англоязычном портале [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41886180/13064906).

Я так до конца и не понял, почему через реестр программа не хотела запускаться.

Comment: Есть вариант, установить службу приложения.